# Having trouble with predicate in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to right a predicate in Prolog that accepts an item, a list, and a number, and checks to see if the item is in the list that number of times. For example

```
count(7,[3,7],X).
```

would return `X=1`.

```
count(7,[3,7],1).
```

would return `true`

This is what I have so far

```
count_occur(A,[0|B],D).
count_occur(A,[A|C],D) :- count_occur(A,C,D1), D is D1+1.
count_occur(A,[B|C],D) :- count_occur(A,C,D).
```

I am very new to Prolog and really struggling to understand this programming paradigm.

What I am trying to do is to see if the first item in the list matches the passed-in value (A), if it does increment D and check again against the remainder of the list. This is how I would do it in lisp or another language anyway. Could really use some help, been at this for a while and it just isn't clicking for me.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first line? And you have to handle the case of having an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have prolog right now to test it, but I would try it like that:

```
count_occur(A, [], 0).
count_occur(A, [A|T], D):- count_occur(A, T, D1), D is D1 + 1.
count_occur(A, [B|T], D):- A \= B, count_occur(A, T, D).
```

The idea is that if the list is empty, there is 0 occurrences of each element. The rest is almost the same as yours as I think that it is correct.

The only difference is that I have added `A \= B`, which should mean `A \neq B`. I think that otherwise it will accept `A == B`, which might lead to `count_occur(3, [3], 0).` being true. You should check about that.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot that worked! A/= B part wasn't necessary though, so that means I needed to change my first fact to get it to work. I can see now how come changing D to 0 would be true in the base case, but I am curious how come prolog can resolve the case where the list has only one item in it. Wouldn't a call like count_occur(7, [7], X) have no rule that applies to it because there wouldn't be two values in the list to bind to B and T or A and T? It works but I don't quite understand how come yet.

Comment: Well, as far as I remember [7] is equivalent to [7|[]], so it goes to this second rule.

As for the `A/= B`, at least the implementation that I have gives
    ?- count_occur(3, [3], 0).
    true .
which I don't think is correct.